# Is there a way to execute something in the console of a website without opening the DevTools?

Tags: javascript, python, web, console

So I was wondering if it is possible to execute JavaScript code or send anything to the console of a website without opening the DevTools.

Like lets say I would like to run the function `debug.start()` in the console. Then I have to open the DevTools > Console and send there `debug.start()`.

But let's say that I would like to execute the function without opening the DevTools at all.
I mean a code, that executes the function `debug.start()` for me.

Is there a way to do so? And if so, then is it possible to do that with Python because I know python the best.

Comment: I suppose you could write a browser extension that allows you to execute whatever commands you want without manually entering them each time.  As to whether or not you could use Python to write an extension for any given browser, I imagine that's a separate research effort.

Comment: You can use selenium or playwright. E.g. `driver.execute_script(….)` or `page.evaluate(…)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/) is what you are looking for. This is a browser extension that allows you to write scripts in JavaScript and execute them on websites or on specific pages.

On [this page](https://www.tampermonkey.net/scripts.php), you can find user scripts.